Can I use drinking water mixed with Seachem's Prime to top off my tank's water? (salt)
I have a few buddies in a saltwater tank and some of their water has evaporated. Can I just get some drinking water and mix it with Prime before adding it in? I usually purchase distilled water but was uncertain if this was overkill.
Thank you so much for your help!

We don't know what is in your local water, so we can't tell you whether it would be bad for the fish or not.

@keshlam absolutely fair point, let me edit the question. I was planning to utilize filtered drinking water. Thank you so much
